# className applied when using "addItem"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `addItem` to add a value to a list from another component

I am adding it to `this.state.movies`. It appears, however it has the inactive/noresults `className` applied to it.

How do I determine which styling is applied to an item that has not appeared yet (ie using `addItem`)? Thanks

Full example on Codesandbox is here. Add an `movie` to the list and you will see it gets the stying applied: https://codesandbox.io/s/3OGK2pP9

## Parent component where I add the item

```
<CreateNew addItem={item => this.setState({ movies: [{ name: item.value.name, genres: item.genres }].concat( movies, ), })} />
```

## Child component that creates the item

```
class CreateNew extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: '',
      genres: '',
    };
  }
  handleSubmit1 = (e, value) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.addItem(this.state);
  };
  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      value: { name: e.target.value },
      genres: [{ name: 'Test', type: 1 }, { name: 'Foo', type: 10 }],
    });
  };
  render() {
    const { value, genres } = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit1}>
        Add a new movie
        <input onChange={this.onChange} value={value} type="text" />
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Was related to filtering on my const `x` instead of my state `this.state.movies`.

I changed it from `const filteredResults = andFilter({x}, Object.keys(selectedFilters));` to `const filteredResults = andFilter({this.state.movies}, Object.keys(selectedFilters));

Comment: Yes- I was not applying the result to my state- I changed it from `const filteredResults = andFilter({x}, Object.keys(selectedFilters));` to `const filteredResults = andFilter({this.state.movies}, Object.keys(selectedFilters));